# Как сделать валидацию полей ввода пароля?

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать валидацию полей input Пароля и Подтверждение пароля? Если пароли совпадают, то при нажатии кнопки должно появляться окно с приветствием, если нет, сообщение об ошибке.

```
 function validate() {
  const saveBtn = document.getElementById('savebtn');
  let pass = document.querySelector('.input__password').value;
  let repass = document.querySelector('.input__repassword').value;
  saveBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (pass === repass) {
      alert('Welcome!');
    } else {
      alert('пароли не совпадают');
    }
  });
}
validate();
```

В таком виде появляется в любом случае окно с приветствием, почему не работает проверка?

Comment: Как минимум без html тут нельзя ничего сказать. А в целом можно включить отладку и посмотреть пошагово код и его значения на каждом шаге

Comment: Внесите объявление переменных ``pass`` и ``repass`` внутрь обработчика события ``click``

Comment: Нужно переменные внести внутрь функции клика, а не наружи держать, ведь до события они не определены

Comment: Большое спасибо, после внесения переменных внутрь обработчика, все заработало.